# Как создать одну таблицу из двух

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть две таблицы:

```
| A | B | C |
```

и

```
| AА | D | E |  F |
```

Мне нужно построить такой запрос, который даст на выходе

```
| A  |   B  |   C  | null | null |  null |
| AA | null | null |  D   |  E   |  F    |
```

Т.е. сложить две таблицы в одну, причем поля А и АА должны складываться в одной колонке, т.к. там разные данные одинакового формата.
Пытаюсь реализовать это JOIN-ами, но выходит только так:

```
| A | B | C | AA | D | E |
```

Подскажите пример реализации, и возможно ли это в рамках MYSQL вообще?..

**Обновление**

Важный момент: количество колонок в таблицах - разное, и при формировании результата будет использоваться условие выборки WHERE A >= value1 и WHERE АA >= value1 для каждой таблицы соответственно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то Вам нужен [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

```
  SELECT
       A
       ,B
       ,C
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
    FROM
       Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
       AA
       ,NULL
       ,NULL
       ,D
       ,E
    FROM
       Table2
```

Comment: похоже на идеал... а как отсортировать результат по полю А (АА)?..

Comment: Оберните этот запрос в еще один 'SELECT':

'SELECT * FROM (SELECT...) X ORDER BY <поле>'

Answer (score 0):

В принципе нечего сложно нет:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.A, t2.AA), t1.B, t1.C, t2.D, t2.E  FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
```

Comment: ошибку синтаксиса выводит...